# How to center align a widget inside card in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, error-handling

im stuck somewhere in my design, Im trying to put 2 containers that have further few Childs and they are all wrapped inside a card widget. Now the problem im facing is that I want to align my widgets at an exact center position but when I do it on one screen size, it disperses on the other screen size and vice versa. Im not able to make a generic design for this part to be able to work on all types of screen sizes. Below are the attached screenshots for reference.

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

if you see the thumbs up and gift icon, they're not aligned exactly in the middle of the greyed area of the container. I want them exactly to be centered. Right now if I center them on one screen, they overflow on other and vice versa. Below is the code for these parts.

```
 //code for card 1, i-e: 98/100 card
SizedBox(
                height: 193,
                width: 180,
                child: Card(
                  color: Color(0xfffaf5f5),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.16,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              '98',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Karla',
                                fontSize: 60,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xff54c19f),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '/100',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Karla',
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xff75777d),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'images/pouce-ok.png',
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //code for card 2, i-e: 129pts card
              SizedBox(
                height: 193,
                width: 180,
                child: Card(
                  color: Color(0xfffaf5f5),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.16,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              '129',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Karla',
                                fontSize: 60,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xff478dd0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'pts',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Karla',
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xff75777d),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'images/cadeaux.png',
                          width: 35,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I want them all to be centered align regardless of the screen size, any help would be appreciated, thnx in advance.

Comment: wrap child: Image.asset(
                          'images/pouce-ok.png',
                          width: 30,
                        ), this inside Center Widget

Comment: already tried man, didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys I appreciate your help but I figured it out myself after experimenting different techniques and spending heck lot if time. so basically I was looking at the wrong place in the code. I shouldn't have provided a fixed height of the card instead by using a media query in place of height property of SizedBox I did it responsive relative to all the devices. below is the code of how I did it:

```
//old code
SizedBox(
            height: 193,
            width: 180,
            child: Card(
              color: Color(0xfffaf5f5),
              child: Column(...

//new code
SizedBox(
            //this is the how the height should be given
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
            width: 180,
            child: Card(
              color: Color(0xfffaf5f5),
              child: Column(....
```

So that's how I have achieved it. Thankyou for your help again, Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

That should do it.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. Although I have posted an answer, you can check it out :) thnx.